# Collect Data from User in Workflow - custom email - collect data URL creation

Tags: workflow, email, url, hyperlink

When I'm creating a workflow in SP 2010 Foundation, I'm using the collect data from user action.  I'm able to add it and by default it sends the default e-mail to the user asking to action the item.  I DON'T want to use the default e-mail for other reasons, I want to customize an e-mail with a link that says something like "Click here to approve" which would take the user to the "collect data from user" form (which has the buttons Save Draft, Complete Task, Cancel).

Dynamic string creation seems like a ton of work for something so simple and I've tried FORM_URN which I heard can generate this URL.  Has anyone tried this?  I've seen tons on getting a link to edit the task but I want to spit out the link to the CDFU (collect data from user) screen.

Comment: Could you give some hints on how you associate task ID with form ID? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up building the string myself which wasn't that difficult after I was able to associate the source list record to the task using a second workflow once a task was created.  Don't try and send out the e-mail immediately after the CDFU is initiated as for some reason the task ID is not ready.  I had to create another workflow on the task list that associates the original list ID of the record to the ask and then sends the e-mail that builds the string.